# Navigation between UIViewControllers IOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm stuck with a problem and ask for your help.
It's about navigation within a UINavigationController stack.

For exemple my IOS app can have this type of hierachy

[1]-->[2]-->[3]

Means that the first controller push the second which push the third. How can i create a button in the third one which makes me going back directly to the first controller like this

[3]-->[1]

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `UINavigationController`'s method `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`, e.g. from within your UIViewController:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

[`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has the following method:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

You just need to create a button that calls that method.

Comment: ok, i'm going to try it. But for some reason i've a problem that avoid me to try, i think you gave me the solution Thankss